# Sed/awk/tr - Remove Multi Line String and Format

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have an output from a query I ran on elasticsearch which I want to parse to provide a csv with two entries per line.

The sample output I am working with is:

```
      {
     "_index": "file__mdata",
     "_type": "assets",
     "_id": "24607c5a-2c6g-416a-ab88-58fha56a34ac",
     "_version": 6,
     "found": true,
     "_source": {
        "meta": {
           "Item Id": "dd0bd495-a4af-49c0-95e3-554097ed6a35",
        }
     }
  },
  {
     "_index": "file__mdata",
     "_type": "assets",
     "_id": "fgtaf7g2-32b8-4278-8ca0-3bc0g30ae592",
     "_version": 8,
     "found": true,
     "_source": {
        "meta": {
           "Item Id": "de2acr1d-5d1b-4171-85d7-d76adbf50cc3",
        }
     }
  }
```

The plan is to end up with the following:

```
"_id": "24607c5a-2c6g-416a-ab88-58fha56a34ac","Item Id": "dd0bd495-a4af-49c0-95e3-554097ed6a35"
```

So I got to running the output through grep -a 5 to filter the outside areas before piping the stream through sed with the s flag per line to remove each line in-between (using regEx on the version line). The output ended up looking like:

```
         "_id": "24607c5a-2c6g-416a-ab88-58fha56a34ac",




           "Item Id": "dd0bd495-a4af-49c0-95e3-554097ed6a35",





     "_id": "fgtaf7g2-32b8-4278-8ca0-3bc0g30ae592",




           "Item Id": "de2acr1d-5d1b-4171-85d7-d76adbf50cc3",
```

Trying to run tr to remove white space doesn't seem to have the desired effect and the only output I can seem to achieve places all of the remaining text on one line.

I am feeling the multi-pipe sed approach is convoluted and there has to be a more straight forward approach which can handle a multi-line entry. This could be achieved in notepad++ for example so I am hoping that I can end up with a script I can run over a very large output where a text editor will struggle to open.

Any suggestions? apologies if this all feels very straight forward to some of you but I am lost in the weeds.

Answer (score 1):

If sampleInput is a test file with your input, then this:

```
awk '/"_id"/ {printf "%s", $0} /"Item Id"/ {printf "%s\n", $0}' sampleInput
```

generates this:

```
 "_id": "24607c5a-2c6g-416a-ab88-58fha56a34ac",           "Item Id": "dd0bd495-a4af-49c0-95e3-554097ed6a35",
 "_id": "fgtaf7g2-32b8-4278-8ca0-3bc0g30ae592",           "Item Id": "de2acr1d-5d1b-4171-85d7-d76adbf50cc3",
```

Comment: For robustness you probably want to tighten up the regexes by detecting at least the beginning of the line, like in Ed's answer.  For example, `/^\s*"_id"/` is already an improvement.  I wrote something simple that would (1) work and (2) be easy to understand, so you could easily tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'^[[:space:]]+|,[[:space:]]*$' -v OFS=, '/"_id":/{id=$2} /"Item Id":/{print id, $2}' file
"_id": "24607c5a-2c6g-416a-ab88-58fha56a34ac","Item Id": "dd0bd495-a4af-49c0-95e3-554097ed6a35"
"_id": "fgtaf7g2-32b8-4278-8ca0-3bc0g30ae592","Item Id": "de2acr1d-5d1b-4171-85d7-d76adbf50cc3"
```